# Add variable to onClick() event inside of prepend() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting a syntax error, however, I just can't get it right.

What I am trying to achieve:

`<input type='checkbox' onclick="document.location.href ='http://google.com'" >`

I need to add the *onclick* event inside of `prepend()` method where the destination is a variable.

I am including my original function:

```
function AddTickBoxesToOptions() {
            $('.filter-options-content .item').each(function(){
                var FilterLink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
                $(this).prepend("<input class='filterCheckBox' type='checkbox' onClick='document.location.href='" + FilterLink + "' >");
            });
        }
```

---

A snippet (not working one...):

```js
var link = "https://google.com";
$('#myDiv').prepend("<input type='checkbox' onClick='document.location.href='" + link + "' >")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>
  the div
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at your HTML using inspect element. You will see the discrepancy.

Comment: Also, don't use inline javascript as already said because of XSS vulnerability as we could edit the HTML and also becomes hard to debug at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to add the `onclick` attribute, it is better practice to bind the event handler via JS code, and that way you will avoid problems with referencing variables:

```js
var link = "https://google.com";
$('#myDiv').prepend($("<input>").attr("type", "checkbox").click(function () {
    document.location.href = link;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>
  the div
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. That worked perfectly! Look a lot more professional in comparison to what I have tried. Lesson learned. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practise to write inline javascript code, check my code. I have created a function and call it from onclick event.

```js
var link = "https://google.com";
$('#myDiv').prepend("<input type='checkbox' onclick='exec()' />");

function exec(){ document.location.href=link; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>
  the div
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: From a point of view, yes it is. But it's better to separate javascript code from html tag.

Comment: I completely agree with the last point, but then why not do it completely ;-)

Comment: Can you explain to me how is the `exec()` function inline? It's not in-between the html so I am a bit confused :/

Comment: You can get the element using the id or class (e.g. document.getElementById) and then assign onclick event to that element. So the html tag will not contain any function call. e.g onclick.

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't create an event handler when you write it this way(You can do it in html code because the browser reads it automatically when DOM is ready). So you have to define the event handler by Javascript.
A better way to do it:

```js
$('.filter-options-content .item').each(function(){
    var FilterLink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    var newElem = $(this).prepend("<input class='filterCheckBox' type='checkbox' >");
    newElem.data('targetLocation', FilterLink).click(function(){
        document.location.href = $(this).data('targetLocation');
    });
});
```